# jQuery selectable() post via ajax issue where the selections loop their history before posting

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a table that a user can select multiple rows. Selected rows have unique ID which is then aggregated into a string and POSTed to a php file. It all works fantastic except I have one problem. If the rows are selected, re-selected a number of times it does not POST the last status of the selection. So when I look into the log this is what I basically see:

```
14_629_2 view.php:541
14_629_15 view.php:541
14_629_2 view.php:541
14_629_15 view.php:541
14_629_2;14_629_15 view.php:541
14_629_15 view.php:541
```

This is two rows by the way. So the last state could be both rows selected `14_629_2;14_629_15 view.php:541` , but it would post the  `14_629_15 view.php:541` instead, for some reason. It's as if it keeps cache or history of selections made and then loops and dumps everything in one spur.. and sometimes messes up.

I basically need it to keep track of only the current selection, no history.

---

Code I use:

```
  <script> 
    $('#t1').selectable({
      filter:'tbody tr',
      stop: function(event, ui){
      var map = $( this ).find( ".ui-selected" ).map(function() {return this.id;}).get().join(";");
      // var result = $( "#plate" ).empty().html(map);
      $('#batch_send').click(function (){
         $(function() {
            $.ajax({
               url: 'batch_send.php',
               type: 'POST',
               data: 'variable='+map,
               success: function(data) {
                  $('.display_div').html(map);
                  console.log(map); 
               }
            });
         });
      });
      }
    });
    </script>
```

I'm new to javascript so this must be some obvious mistake...

Answer (score 0):

Solution:

The reason it looped was because the ajax request was in a function.

So I rewrote the code to make it a bit more simple

```
var map;
$("#t1").selectable({
  filter:'tbody tr',
  cancel: 'a, #slct_ignore, thead',
      stop: function(event, ui) {
      map = $(this).find( ".ui-selected" ).map(function() {return this.id;}).get().join(";");
    }
});

$("#batch_send").click(function() {
    $.ajax({
            url: 'batch_send.php',
            type: 'POST',
            data: 'variable='+map,
            success: function(data) {
                                    $("#plate").html(map);
                                    $(".display_div").html(map);
                                    }
          });
});
```